# Python and ClearCase setview

Tags: python, clearcase

I would like to set to a clearcase view from a python script, and then execute commands within that view. I have tried using various methods outlined here:

[subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)

but I have not had any success. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't recommend setting a view, because [`setview`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm) itself spawn a new process.
I really prefer working with `/view/viewTag/aVob/...` after [starting the view](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm) (`cleartool startview viewTag` )

The "spawn process" issue makes the all thing too complex in my opinion, and explains why you have technotes like:

- "[Setting into a view from a shell script does not process the remaining commands in the script](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21119859)".

> Any commands that appear after the execution of `cleartool setview cmview` are not processed because a shell is spawned off with `exec()`, which replaces the current program with a new program.
>
> This means current process's text and code segments, which in this case is the script that contains all the commands, is replaced by the program getting executed, which is the shell invoked by running `cleartool setview cmview`.
> Hence, none of the commands are processed beyond the point of invocation of the `setview`.

- "[How spawned shell is handled by issuing setview -exe or -login and affect on subshell process](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21503973)"

> The `-exec` variable will start a subshell process and invoke the specified command in the dynamic view specified. Control is then returned to the parent shell once the command has finished.
> **The `-exec` will not set the view in the parent shell process**.
> The `-exec` spawned subshell will inherit the Environment variables of the parent shell process; however, the Environment variables created in the child shell will not pass back into the parent shell.

So if you *really* want to use `setview`, you could (not tested directly myself):

- have a python script calling `setview`
- but that `setview` call would be with an `-exec` parameter being another python script (doing what you want to do when that `/vobs` is configured with the content of said set view.

Comment: I have a problem with accessing the views through /view. I am trying to run a set of commands in all views, to do this I would have to set each view to make the view available through /view. Also, this script needs to be run regularly and views are only available through /view for temporary amount of time. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @user1347345: just don't. If you know the name of the view you need to access, start it and it will be there at `/view/viewTag/...`. Pass that `viewTag` name as a parameter to your scripts, and they will access the right path. Much simpler than dealing with sub-shell.

Comment: @user1347345 I have edited my answer with a possible '`setview`' solution... but I still find the all process too cumbersome. Using directly the full path would be the preferred way.

Comment: Some commands can be executed within the viewtag directly (using startview command) in the view directory. However I also found out that some commands can only be executed when /vobs/litho is set, therefor I use the setview -exec. 

Note: setview -exec will take longer to process. Because it need to start/set the view (does some stuff in the background). Where startview is more 'lightweight'.

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your fast reply. In our company we have `ccmake` a wrapper, I think, to build the source-code in the stream. This command expects a valid /vobs/litho link to the view content.

Comment: Ow, I think it's a modified version of this: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/ccmake.1.html

Comment: @danger89 Ok, I haven't been using ccmake, so I wasn't aware of that specific limitation.

Answer (score 3):

Old thread, but i just had to work on this issue , so maybe of help .

In your python script

```
process = subprocess.Popen('usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview viewName')
(out, err) = process.communicate('python script2Name')
```

the .communicate can be passed new commands, as if you were passing it to a new shell (terminal).

Another way to do it would be

```
process = subprocess.Popen('usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview -exec "whatever command you want inside view" viewName')
(out, err) = process.communicate()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Additional question: don't you know, is there a way to print output of the script before it ends? I'd like to start a build in that manner, but process.communicate will wait till the end of the process. In my case it takes ~30 mins =(

Comment: Have a look at this if you are really want to have it. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2017/interacting-with-a-long-running-child-process-in-python/
I actually have long builds as well, but chose not to try live debug, as it way running as part of a Jenkins stage anyway. Not worth to live debug in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the link and for the advice, it seems like it is not worth to try it in my case as well, can leave it as it is now