# Clearcase running commands from a script (error: Bad phone number)

Tags: clearcase

I have a small shell titled xrunner.sh.

```bash
   
#!/bin/bash
ct checkout -nc parentFolder
cd parentFolder/
ct mkdir -nc directory
ct checkin -nc directory
cd ..
ct checkin -nc parentFolder
pwd
```

When the commands are run individually on the CLI they all work fine, When run from the bash however the following is thrown back at me:

```
ct: bad phone number -- parentFolder
ct: bad phone number -- -nc
ct: bad phone number -- checkout
: No such file or directory
ct: bad phone number -- directory
ct: bad phone number -- -nc
ct: bad phone number -- mkdir
ct: bad phone number -- directory
ct: bad phone number -- -nc
ct: bad phone number -- checkin
: No such file or directory
ct: bad phone number -- parentFolder
ct: bad phone number -- -nc
ct: bad phone number -- checkin
```

Would anyone happen to know why this is or point me to some web reference that explains this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means you don't have defined the alias 'ct' properly

add:

```
alias ct=/path/to/cleartool
```

Note: if you want to add a directory to source control, don't forget to call mkelem

```
cleartool mkelem -mkpath dir1 -c "a comment"
```

See "[Command line add to Source control of a directory with files in a dynamic view returns Error](http://cleartool%20mkelem%20-mkpath%20dir1http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21237733)".

Notes:

- as [this thread suggests](http://objectmix.com/python/343454-re-why-chdir-command-doesnt-work-client-get_transport.html), even if the alias is already defined, a `ct setview` won't allow further `ct` commands to work, because `setview` spawns a sub-shell. See for instance "[Python and ClearCase `setview`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252436/python-and-clearcase-setview/10252612#10252612)" for more on `setview`.
  So `ct` will work, except if you have further `ct` commands in a script after a `ct setview`.
- Just for information, here the the [man page for the `/usr/bin/ct` command](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/hp-ux/man1/ct.1.html)

```
    ct(1)
    NAME
    ct - spawn getty to a remote terminal (call terminal)
```

> The UNIX command "`/usr/bin/ct`" dials a phone number, where a modem connected to a terminal should be awaiting for the call, and then spawns a getty(1M) process to that terminal.
>   The "getty" process sets the terminal type, modes, speed and line discipline, and then invokes the "login" process, which in turn will execute a shell when a user authenticates correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you get with `ct: bad phone number...` is because there is actually another binary called `ct`. You can run `type -p ct` in bash to find which  (too many years since I had the same problem so I do not remember where it was (/usr/xpg4/bin ??)).

So as VonC suggest, make an alias for ct.