# Creating Activities in a Snapshot View in ClearCase

Tags: view, clearcase, snapshot-view

I would like to create an activity for my ClearCase snapshot view, but you cannot [ct setview](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/c_about_setup_view_ucmact.htm) to a snapshot and when I try to just [ct mkactivity](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkactivity.htm) I get the following error:

> my_snapshot> ct mkact
>
> Create activity with automatically generated name?  [yes] y
>
> [27204] mkact_pre -- trigger firing
>
> Stream feature 'MkactForbidden' does not allow creation of activities.
>
> cleartool: Warning: Trigger "UTS_mkact_pre" has refused to let mkactivity proceed.
>
> cleartool: Error: Unable to create activity.

Can you create activities in ClearCase snapshot views? Or are you restricted to creating activities in dynamic views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [`cleartool setview`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm) is only for dynamic view (see "[Python and ClearCase setview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252436/python-and-clearcase-setview)", for instance, for more).

[`mkact`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkactivity.htm) can create activity in any view, dynamic or snapshot, but in your case, a pre-op trigger on the `mkact` operation prevents you to create it.
You could try and set an *existing* activity: you might have to unselect the current one (`ct setact -none`) first.

But mainly you need to check with your ClearCase admin why this trigger prevents you to make any activity, which in effects prevents you to checkout or rebase or deliver in this stream.

Comment: It looks like I cannot unset and reassign an existing activity to my snapshot view, so I will have to contact my admin to determine why I am being prevented from creating the activity. Thanks again.