# rsync local code with a remote clearcase dynamic view

Tags: clearcase, rsync

I want to syncrhonize a local path with a dynamic clearcase view hosted in a remote machine  only accesible through ssh:

local:/me  | <==  ssh == | me@remote_host:/vobs/me/view_1

Those familiar with clearcase know that in order  create a dynamic view you must issue the following command in the remote host 'cleartool setview view_1' where view_1 is the reference to the pre-existant tagged dynamic view, problem is that when i try to run that command with the --rsync-path option to rsync, it never comes back:

```
$ rsync '--rsync-path=`cleartool setview view_BAAAAAD;/usr/bin/rsync`'  
 me@remote_host:/vobs/me/view_1 .
```

cleartool: Error: View tag not found: "setview view_BAAAAAD"

So it seems the command is actually issued, yet when i fed the correct tag:

```
$ rsync '--rsync-path=`cleartool setview view_1;/usr/bin/rsync`'  
me@remote_host:/vobs/me/view_1 .
```

Then it never comes back, when i use the command in the remote host through ssh it doesn't ask for input (neither tty or stdin).

So i'm stuck with using static views. Any idea?

PD:

- The actual scheme is a little bit more complicated since the ssh connection is forwarded
- I can use static views but i'd prefer    dynamic    ones
- I cannot install any daemon or script on the remote host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in order create a dynamic view you must issue the following command in the remote host 'cleartool setview view_1' where view_1 i

No you don't.

- You only have to start it: `cleartool startview view_1`
- And you can use it in `/view/view_1/vobs/avob/....`

[Avoid `setview` which creates a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309) in which the PATH might not be correct.

Comment: +1 thanks VonC, i stand corrected so my only chance is using the /view/view_1/vobs... path, i knew that beforehand but didn't like to use it since a see a few metadata files i don't see when i use the dynamic view which i can avoid using the --exclude option in the rsync. As soon as i can put my hands on the server and check it, i'll accept your answer