# can't create clearcase component?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I can create ClearCase UCM component from ClearCase project explorer but can't create it through command line.
This is what I have used:

```
cleartool mkcomp -nc -root /vobs/spider1_pvob/bat1 bat1@/vobs/spider1_pvob
cleartool: Error: Unable to resolve component root directory "/vobs/spider1_pvob/bat1": ClearCase object not found
cleartool: Error: Unable to create component.
```

What would be the correct command to use for creating this component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always create a component in a ClearCase view, using a vob and not a pvob for the root directory.
So in your case, you would need to have:

- a dynamic view started

```
cleartool startview myView
```

- the vob mounted:

```
cleartool mount /vobs/spider1_vob
```

- that same view set:

```
cleartool setview myView
```

(that ways, `/vobs` reflects the content of the view `myView`)

Once your view is properly started and set, then you can do

```
cleartool mkcomp -nc -root /vobs/spider1_vob/bat1 bat1@/vobs/spider1_pvob
```

Note that I use a vob `/vobs/spider1_vob/(bat1)` for the root directory, even though the component (which is an UCM metadata) is declared in a pvob: `@/vobs/spider1_pvob`

See "[What are the precautions to be taken while creating a clearcase component?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16737500/6309)" and "[cannot see pvob on clearcase GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16943275/6309)" for the difference between a pvob and a vob:
The root directory of a component should be in a vob, not a pvob.

- A pvob contains the *definition* of a component.
- A vob contains its data (files and directories)

I use a dynamic view here, since the only way for a path starting with /vobs is in Unix, after a [cleartool setview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15666598/6309).

If you don't set a dynamic view, you can still use it with the full path:

```
/view/myView/vobs/spide1_vob
```

(since `/view` is the mounting point for *all* the dynamic views)