# Unable to add a component to clear case UCM

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am facing the problem described in this article [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21243336)

So I follow the solution [described](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?&rs=984&uid=swg21243311)

As soon as I choose my snapshot view, it says: `Cannot create component`
Is it something related to rights? The error message is vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then don't bother with the GUI: try it through a shell with cleartool.
See "[can't create clearcase component?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966444/6309)" (which is using a dynamic view, but you can adapt to use your snapshot view).