# Base ClearCase path meaning

Tags: clearcase

```
/vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/common@@/main/2/nVARUTL.cxx@@/main/nz_mig/1
```

Can someone explain the meaning of the above line?

Jim

Comment: A similar path is possible in UCM as well (not only Base)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **[extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309)** which references:

- the version 1 of `nVARUTL.cxx` in branch `main/nz_mig`,
- itself accessible in the version 2 of the folder `common` in branch `main`

See more at "[pathnames_ccase](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/pathnames_ccase.htm)".

The `@@` references the element (`common` or `nVARUTL.cxx`), followed by their versions (branches/version).

```
element-pname@@version-selector
```

Since the path starts with `/vobs`, it means you are accessing that version through a [view set (`cleartool setview`) on Unix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18457541/6309).

See as an example "[About the version-extended path](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_version_path.htm)"

---

Note that each elements are selected by their own versions.

So your config spec shows only the versions of `nVARUTL.cxx`: `/main/nz_mig/1`, with branch `nz_mig` coming from `main/14`:

[image: http://oi62.tinypic.com/35n0qqr.jpg]

**This has nothing to do with the version of the parent folder `common`**.

That parent folder '`common`' is selected by the version `/main/2`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but don't understand the 2nd line. What's accessible in the version 2 of the folder common? I see nz_mig is spin off /main/14, not /main/2.

Comment: @user3519903 can you post a screenshot of the version tree of `nVARUTL.cxx`?

Comment: here: http://tinypic.com/r/35n0qqr/8. A build process is generating a list of change set from CQ tickets. I can see the path is right like this in CQ: /vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/common/nVARUTL.cxx@@/main/nz_mig/1

Comment: @user3519903 the initial extended path name in your question details the version of `common`, then `nVARUTL.cxx`. But your version tree only shows the version of `nVARUTL.cxx`. I have edited my answer.

Comment: I've uploaded the vtree of its parent folder /common here:http://tinypic.com/r/2wf8m0o/8. Why does /common@@/main/2 mean here? The file nVARUTL.cxx was added at /common@@/main/2? I don't understand is why the path is not "/vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/common/nVARUTL.cxx@@/main/nz_mig/1", but "/vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/common@@/main/2/nVARUTL.cxx@@/main/nz_mig/1". What's the different?

Comment: What are you referring to by "itself" in your 2nd point of your first post?

Comment: @user3519903 it means that whatever returned you `nVARUTL.cxx@@/main/nz_mig/1` did so by accessing `nVARUTL.cxx` *after having selected first `common@@/main/2`: "itself" means `nVARUTL.cxx`: to access it, it accessed first the parent folder `common@@/main/2`.

Comment: Now, I don't know what returned `/common@@/main/2/nVARUTL.cxx@@/main/nz_mig/1`: obviously not your view, or it would have selected another version for `common`, as your second picture shows. But in the context of your *initial* question, those are the versions used: `common@@/main/2`, then `nVARUTL.cxx@@/main/nz_mig/1`.

Comment: I traced down to the script has this line "cleartool setcs –tag build_view $cs", and inside the $cs file, it has the following format. I can see they are separated into two columns, not sure if this is a problem.

    # CR00265282
    element "/vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/calibration/calibrationEngine.h"           /main/nz_mig/1
    # CR00274091
    element  "/vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/common@@/main/2/nVARUTL.cxx"               /main/nz_mig/2
    # CR00274091
    element "/vobs/trms/NVaR/DSR/simulationEngine/common@@/main/2/nVARUTL.h"                 /main/nz_mig/2

Comment: @user3519903 that means `$cs` is the new config spec your are setting to the view `build_view`. And `$cs` included those version selectors, and that is all right. It doesn't explain why those exact versions have been assigned to `$cs`, but I believe i have fully answered your initial question.

Comment: @user3519903 "It doesn't explain why those exact versions have been assigned to `$cs`": actually, it does a bit: those versions represents `CR00265282` (possible a `CR`: ClearQuest Record)