# Is clearcase path is a standard one -- '@@' and string after that

Tags: windows, emacs, path, diff, clearcase

is the clearcase path syntax is universal one.

```
my_source.c@@\main\10.1_bugfix\another_branch\0
```

is this path is standard one? 
I invoked the following in emacs and it is working. how does emacs diff understand this path. somehow clearcase informs operating system how to interpret that path. or emacs-diff know of this path syntax?

```
$ diff my_source.c@@\main\10.1_bugfix\another_branch\0 my_source.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an **[extended path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/988904/6309)**.

It is working with [dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309), which give access to the branches and  versions of an element.

See "[Base ClearCase path meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23528243/6309)".

In your case, you access the version 0 of the branch `main\10.1_bugfix\another_branch`.

See also the IBM technote "[About the version-extended path](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/about_version_path.htm)" for an example, and [`pathnames_ccase`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/images/ver_ext_pname.gif) for the doc:

[image: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/content/nl/en-us/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/images/ver_ext_pname.gif]

> You can add characters to the end of a relative or full path name, turning it into a VOB-extended path name.
>   **VOB-extended path names that specify versions of elements are the most commonly used; they are called version-extended path names**.

Comment: how does emacs understand the version-extended file path? assuming emacs uses operating system services for opening the files, how the operating system know about this path. does os have some kind of hook to clearcase to understand this path syntax?

Comment: @vanangamudi the OS knows about this path because a dynamic view uses MVFS (Multi-Version FileSystem), linked with the kernel and defining an new filesystem (which in the end is a collection of folders and files).

Comment: thanks a lot. now I get this. the file-path is supported by a file-system.