# view-extended path example for another windows machine in the domain

Tags: clearcase

Assume there are two WINDOWS Client Machine running clearcase dynamic view and connected to the same domain and logged in by the same domain account.
Windows Machine 1 has View1
Windows Machine 2 has View2

Using view-extended pathname is it possible to access files/directories of view2 from Machine1?
If yes, how?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of: dynamic views are using [MVFS (MultiVersion filesystem)](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21230196) which is not easily shareable over the network.
You can map a view to a drive letter, but I would be surprised if that drive could be shared by Windows.
As mentioned in "[About dynamic views on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122505)":

> All dynamic views started on a Windows client are available from the local MVFS drive, which by default is the `M` drive.

The alternative would be to start `view2` on `Machine1`

Note that with **[extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31424471/6309)**, you can indeed access version referenced by view2 from view1. What you won't be able to access are private elements and checked out elements (stored in view2 view storage).

Answer (score -1):

You should, in theory, be able to use "\view\view2\vob1\dir1\file1" to access "file1" in "view2" from any ClearCase host, assuming that \vob1 is mounted.

You may have to start the view first.