# Using python to check out a file (cleartool)

Tags: python, cleartool

I'm wondering how to completely automate a checkout. I've tried

```
os.system('cleartool co ' + pathname)
```

but that still prompts me to enter a comment about the checkout. Adding more os.system() commands right after doesn't quite work -- they only execute after I've entered the comment.

I'm looking at using subprocess and maybe Popen, but I don't quite understand how they work from the documentation I can find online.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to enter a comment, a simple -nc would be enough:

```
os.system('cleartool co -nc ' + pathname)
```

See [`cleartool checkout` man page](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_checkout.htm).

If the comment is known, you can add it directly (`-c xxx`)

In both cases, the checkout becomes non-interactive, more suite to batch process.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not entirely certain if I'll be required to have a comment, but upon trying this code, I get a little popup saying that a comment needs to be entered, with an "Abort" button for me to press.

Comment: @Jon I have edited the answer: `-c xxx` or `-nc` means there won't be any popup

Comment: The -c xxx line works beautifully! Thanks so much! Unfortunately, the -nc line doesn't prevent the popup for me. I think -c xxx will be sufficient for my needs, but I'm not certain yet. Anyways, thanks so much, you've helped me significantly.

Comment: @Jon speaking of python, make sure to avoid `cleartool setview` if you are using dynamic view: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309. Use the full path of the dynamic view instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18457541/6309

Comment: Thanks for the links! Views aren't a concern at the moment, but if that becomes necessary, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Popen and communicate to enter the comment after calling cleartool:

```
from subprocess import Popen

p = Popen(['cleartool','co',pathname])

p.communicate("comment\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This worked better than anything I had previously tried with Popen, but it's still not quite doing the trick. I'm still having to manually enter my comment. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: @Jon,  I was looking for the list of commands but the answer below has provided the man page, you can and should use `subprocess.check_call` passing the list of args

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! What would the list of args be in this case? I guess that's the most confusing thing for me. Could I just say subprocess.check_call('cleartool co ' + pathname, 'comment')?