# mkfifo command failing on clearcase vobs

Tags: unix, solaris, clearcase, mkfifo

I am trying to create named pipe in a directory which is created under clearcase's vobs tree (/vobs/something/something) but not checked-in. I am getting this error:

```
"mkfifo: No such device or address"
```

I am not able to understand why pipe creation is failing while other files are getting created. 
I am using Solaris 10. Is there any way I can create named pipes in vobs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/vobs/something/something` means MVFS path with a view set (as in [`cleartool setview`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm)).

First, try the same operation with the fumm path instead of trying to set a view. As I explain in "[Python and ClearCase setview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309)", setting a view creates a sub-shell, with all kinds of side effect for your processes (in term of environment variables and other non-heirted attributes).

So try it in `/views/MyView/vobs/something/something`.

---

Second, regarding pipe, check if [this thread applies to your case](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013856802):

> Just off the top of my head if you using a pipe and not a file, then it should be specified something like this ..

```
destination my_pipe pipe("/data/pipes/net_pipe");
```

> rather than

```
destination my_file file("/data/pipes/net_pipe");
```

---

Note that, for [ClearCase up to 7.0.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21122501):

> ClearCase does not support adding to source control special files such as named pipes, fifos or device files. There are no type mangers available to manage these special files.
>
> Note: Attempts to execute these files in the MVFS is not supported.
>
> WORKAROUNDS:
>
> - Keep multiple versions of directories with device files outside of a VOB and versioned directories/symlinks in a VOB to point to correct directory location outside the VOB.
> - Keep a tar or zip archive of the tree with device files in the VOB, and extract it to a temporary workspace when needed in the development process.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Looks like I will have to choose some other place to create the FIFOs.