# script doesn't run while executing in clearcase

Tags: unix, sh, ksh, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to execute the following build script and it is returning no error but it is not executing the script inside it. there is a view tag with the following name. it can be seen with `cleartool lsview <view-tag>`. I can do `cleartool setview <view-tag>` but it doesn't run the sh /abc/cds/fg/bin/ant -t all.

> CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME=NYC_CYN
>
> cleartool setview -exec "newgrp orange; cd /abc/cds/fg/bin; sh /abc/cds/fg/bin/ant -t all -i ' '" $CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME

Thanks for any help !!

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `setview`. It triggers a sub-shell, which doesn't play well with scripts.
See "[Python and ClearCase setview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309)" for a concrete example on how spawning a process has side effects when it comes to scripts.

Use `cleartool startview <view-tag>` to make sure your dynamic view is started, and then use the full view path:

```
/view/<view-tag>/vobs/YourVobs/....
```

In your case:

```
newgrp orange; 
cd /view/<view-tag>/vobs/abc/cds/fg/bin
sh /view/<view-tag>/vobs/abc/cds/fg/bin/ant -t all -i ' '
```

Comment: VonC, But I am not using windows. its a unix ksh shell the jenkins build remotely. Still I need cleartool startview <view-tag>? thanks for the prompt response

Comment: @user2370590 this is an answer for Unix, with Unix-paths.

Comment: @user2370590 `startview` is not mandatory, just a precaution. And `setview` doesn't bring you anything here, just troubles. It is better to use the full path of the view instead of trying to mount its content on '`/`' (which `setview` does, in a subprocess).

Comment: script is not runing after starting the view and providing the full path /view/$CLEARCASE_VIEWNAME/......

Comment: @user2370590 then `setview` or `starview` isn't the issue. You must first try to rum that script manually to see what command actually works (maybe without the `sh`?). But again, using the full path of the view.