# using SSH to run a cleartool command with agruments on remote a linux machine

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-access, cleartool

when I run this then everything work:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\cwRsync\bin\ssh.exe -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.10.10 -l username /usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview -exec 'pwd' cm_myview
```

however if I have more than two arguments after exec like this:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\cwRsync\bin\ssh.exe -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' 10.10.10.10 -l username /usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview -exec 'cd /user' cm_myview
```

then it will fail with the error: extra argument:"cm_myview"

so right now if there is more than 2 argument after -exec, then it will say those argument are extra, anyone know how I can fix this. Thanks.

I am only running one command which run a script file. But I need to pass arguments to this script file. I think the program think the first argument is the view i am tying to set.

Comment: Put your commands in a script file on the remote host, and pass the file name to `-exec`?

Comment: actually, that is what I am doing. I put all my commands in a script file, but I still need to pass arguments to the script file. If I pass more than one argument, then I will get an error. (I think the program think the first argument is the view i am tying to set, there should be nothing after that)

Comment: To put it simply: you don't need `setview`. You can use the full path of the view you wanted to set.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to use `setview`: it spawns a sub-shell, which won't ever work well with multiple commands.
See "[Python and ClearCase setview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309)" for a concrete example of the kind of issue you will have.

Simply use the **full path of a dynamic view**, as I mention in "[script doesn't run while executing in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22736631/6309)".

```
/view/aView/vobs/...
```

Make sure that this view is started first (`cleartool startview`)

No need for `setview` here.

Comment: I am only running one command (which is to run a script file which contain all my commands), but I need to pass arguments to this script file. If I have any argument, then I will get an error saying anything after the first argument is extra (I think the program think the first argument is the view i am tying to set, there should be nothing after that)

Comment: @help just don't. Trust me. Forget that `setview` ever existed. It is nothing but trouble. Call any script you want with any argument you want. Just not `setview`.