# Dynamic views of ClearCase not integrating in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, clearcase-automation

We use ClearCase as our Version Control Tool. While Integrating Dynamic view to Jenkins in my job at Execute Shell, it is not getting integrated and throwing errors.

My Commands at Execute Shell:

```
/usr/atria/bin/cleartool setview johns 
/usr/atria/bin/cleartool catcs
cd /vob1/pts/
ls
pwd
```

- First thing, it is not identifying the `cleartool` path and view.
- Secondly, it is not entering into VOB (`/vob1/pts`).
  None of the commands working ... like `pwd` and `ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cleartool setview` (as I mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23093316/6309)): it spawns a sub-shell which makes any subsequent command not working (because those commands are executed in the *parent* shell, for which `/vobs` has been assigned to a view)

Always use the **full path of the view**: `/view/yourView/vobs/yourVob`

In your case:

```
cd /view/johns/vobs/pts
/usr/atria/bin/cleartool catcs
ls
pwd
```

If the Jenkins ClearCase Plugin is using setview anyway, then, as explained in this [blog post](http://champasoft.blogspot.fr/2013/01/clearcase-setview-command.html), you must make sure it uses a `-exe` directive:

```
cleartool setview -exec /tmp/script.sh
```

(with `/tmp/script.sh` including all your other commands)

Comment: Could you please give an example for my Queries or change what I need to do for my settings as I mentioned in my Query. I am new to Jenkins integration, I stuck at first instance itself. You can take my view and vob as examples. Thanks Von!

Comment: @SureshKumar Are you using https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+Plugin?

Comment: Yes, I installed ClearCase plugin and using it. I tried setting view in different ways. All were failed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked well! cd /view/johns/vob1/pts.

Comment: @SureshKumar yes, using the full path of a view is always better than trying to "setview" it.