# Clearcase and java process : changing view does not apply

Tags: java, clearcase

i have a simple application, which receives input from a user for a CC stream name, and is suppose to return the content of a specific file from this stream repository.

I have tried doing this using a simple shell script:
user enters stream name,
java receives stream name, runs a process which runs a script "myccscript.sh" which contains "myinput=$1; cleartool setview $myinput" (or something like that).

then i try reading the file and printing it's content in the java side.
BUT, after the process is finished - the view is not the view from the user input - that environment was probably only valid for the process Ive created.

how do i change the clearcase view to the main java process?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [`cleartool setview`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm). It spawns a sub-shell which will make all your other command not working (since they are executed in the parent shell)

Always use the full path of a dynamic view:

```
/view/aView/vobs/aVob/....
```

You will find the very same issue (and the very same advice "don't use setview") in:

- "[Dynamic views of ClearCase not integrating in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23515738/6309)"
- "[using SSH to run a cleartool command with agruments on remote a linux machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23093316/6309)"
- "[script doesn't run while executing in clearcase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22736631/6309)"

You will find a concrete example of that issue in "[Python and ClearCase setview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309)".