# Getting present working view in Clearcase

Tags: python, subprocess, clearcase

I need to find a command to get the active view name from Clearcase, so I can ask the user if they would like to set that as their default path. The following does not work. Any options besides this?

```
out, err = subprocess.Popen([r"cleartool", "xxx", "-xxxxx"],
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
return out
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`cleartool pwv`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_pwv.htm) will only give you the name of the view.
To get the path:

```
cleartool pwv -root
```

`G:\` means probably a snapshot view, since all dynamic views are usually mounted (MVFS) on the drive `M:\` by default (but they could be subst'ed to a drive letter as well).
For snapshot views, a drive letter different from `C:\` means the actual path of the snapshot view has been `subst` (Windows command) to a drive letter in order to shorten its path.

See "[To use the `subst` command to access snapshot views (Windows)](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/t_use_subst_cmd_win.htm)"

> Assigning a snapshot view root directory to a drive letter with the subst command provides slightly better performance than making the snapshot view a shared directory

So if you are on `G:\norbt5_ed_hil_dev` and want the full path after a `cleartool pwv`, you can:

```
cleartool pwv -root
```

If that returns you only `G:\`, then you need to call the commands `subst` to see the full path where `G:\` has been assigned.

```
subst
```

Or, in python (as [in the example](http://mynthon.net/howto/-/python/python%20-%20playground%20-%20playing%20with%20long%20paths%20on%20windows.txt)):

```
os.system('subst')
```

And parse the result.

---

Note: As explained in "[Python and ClearCase `setview`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309)", `pwv` wouldn't work in a **dynamic** view started with `setview` on Unix (`setview` doesn't exist on Windows), because **it creates a sub-process**.
If you are on Unix working with dynamic view, don't use `setview` (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107687/6309)).
Always use [`cleartool startview <view_tag>`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm), and then the full path of the dynamic view:

```
/view/AViewName/vobs/aVob/...
```

A `cleartool pwv -root` would then return `/view/AViewName`.

---

On Windows, if `cleartool pwv` is used in a dynamic view, then the name of the view returned by `cleartool pwv -short` is enough:

The path of the root folder of a dynamic view on Windows is always:

```
m:\view_tag
```

even if the view has been `subst` to a different drive letter.
You don't need the `-root`.

Comment: It worked when I when I first tried it, but now only the short command works. I also tried subprocess.Popen(["cleartool","startview"]) before the command, but that didn't help. Why does it work some times but not others?

Comment: @ShankarKumar is your view a snapshot or a dynamic one?

Comment: @ShankarKumar "Why does it work some times but not others?" Because `cleartool startview` won't assign the dynamic view to a drive letter like `G:`. It will only start and mount the view on `M:` (the MVFS drive). You don't need `G:` (which is or isn't assigned to your view). Use `M:` which is always valid for *any* dynamic started view.

Comment: But why was it returning "M:\view_tag" before and now just "view_tag"? How will I use the full address if I need it? Should I just say "M:\\"+"view_tag"?

Comment: @ShankarKumar yes, to be sure, use `cleartool pwv -short`, and add `M:\\ ` in front of the view tag returned by `pwv`: that will *always* be a valid dynamic view path on Windows.

Comment: @ShankarKumar note that a dynamic view must be started first: `cleartool startview <view_tag>`: if you know which view to start, then you don't even need `pwv`: the path will always be (for a started view) `M:\<view_tag>`. If the view isn't started, but was subst to `G:` in the past, then use the windows command `subst` to get the path it was subst'd: `M:\<view_tag>`: you will get back the view tag that way. Again, `pwv` wouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

`cleartool pwv` is the command to see the active view name.
`cleartool pwv -short` gives a nicer output.

Comment: I tried the following command:

subprocess.Popen([r"cleartool", "pwv", "-short"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()

But it returned "** NONE **". I have ClearCase open so I'm not sure what the problem is..

Comment: What do you get when you type `cleartool pwv -short` in the terminal (outside of Python)?
Usually, "** NONE **" means you don't have a view set.

Comment: cleartool: Error: Cannot get view info for current view: No such file or directory.

Comment: What do you mean by having a view "set"? I have the view shortcut visible in Clearcase

Comment: Is this ClearCase on Windows or Linux?
In Linux, you type `cleartool setview <viewname>`

Comment: Sorry to bug you again, but is there a way to get the full path of the view name? Right now, it returns "norbt5_ed_hil_dev", but I would like the path, like "G:\\norbt5_ed_hil_dev"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to invoke any binary to determine the current view. Outside Python (= in a command shell), the following works:

```
echo $CLEARCASE_CMDLINE | cut -d\  -f2
```

as `cleartool` sets

```
CLEARCASE_CMDLINE=setview eyalroz_2020_01_add_restrict
```

when it puts you into a set-view-shell. This also means that, in Python, you can execute the following:

```
print( os.environ['HOME'].split(' ')[1] )
```