# Not able to set a view on clearcase getting i/p o/p error

Tags: clearcase

Everything was working fine except the storage which was almost full 97% approx and after some time i started getting below errors.

When i tried to vi/ or ls the file i am getting the below errors.

```
ls: cannot open directory .: Input/output error
```

I tried to set a new view which is giving me the below error.

```
cleartool: Warning: Unable to preserve working dir "/vob/*" from old view in new view: Input/output error.
```

cleartool: Warning: Setting current working directory to "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @VonC for your valuable inputs but the issue was due to space crunch on the vob server no sooner the space issue was resolved the `input output error` I was getting got resolved.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if your new view config spec does not reference anything from the old view.

A simple config spec can be used as a test (to check if *all* views have the same issue)

```
element * CHECKEDOUT
element * /main/LATEST
```

You can check that with a new snapshot view and a new dynamic view.

In any case, don't use `setview`: use the full path of the dynamic view:

```
/view/yourDynamicView/vobs/yourVob/...
```

If you are using setview, you should be able to ignore that warning, as it might be related to the old view only (and you want now to work in the new view).

But it would be best to not use `cleartool setview` (as [I have mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24107687/6309)), and use:

```
cleartool startview yourDynamicView
cd /view/yourDynamicView/vobs/yourVob
# start working
cleartool ls
```

Comment: I am getting `Input/output error ` even after setting dynamic view. I am now able to set view. Can this be linked to space issue on the server'

Comment: @yanivx it could be, but first, forget `setview` and see if the symptoms persist when using the actual path of a dynamic view: `/view/aNewViewTag/vobs/aVob`.

Comment: @yanivx also, if you are still using `setview`, make sure you are not in a path starting with `/vob/...` when using `setview`.

Comment: i really tried without setview and used `cleartool startview yourDynamicView` but still the same issue persists. I have asked my sysAdmin to have a look if it is due to space issue

Comment: @yanivx ok but can you ignore the warning? Is your new view working?

Comment: NO, I cannot ignore the warning as the issue is i am not able to see vob elements even the simple `ls ` command is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57395/discussion-between-yanivx-and-vonc).