# Checked out but removed error while merging activities

Tags: clearcase

I wish to merge an activity with my activity, the former activity has new directories and new elements.

I am getting the following error on issuing a merge with the following command

```
ct findmerge activityname@/vob/**  -fcsets -nc -merge
```

The errors are as follows in 2 cases

**Case1:** No new elements created directly the merge command

Errors

```
/vob/**/Build.mk  [checkedout but removed]
/vob/**/file1  [checkedout but removed]
/vob/**/file2  [checkedout but removed]
/vob/**/file3  [checkedout but but removed]


    cleartool: Error: Checked out version, but could not copy data to "/vob/siren/oam/sdh/pkg/Build.mk" in view: Permission denied.
Correct the condition, then uncheckout and re-checkout the element.
```

**Case2:** I created the elements and the directory structure still the same error

**Note:** There are no errors for the elements which already exist in the vob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again your findmerge activity ([as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697198/6309)), but this time, without using `cleartool setview` (meaning without using a path starting with `/vob`, the mounting point for the dynamic view set by `cleartool setview`).

Always use the full path of the destination dynamic view (the one where the merge occur): as [I told you in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24776893/6309), `cleartool setview` is nothing but trouble.

Use:

```
cd /view/yourDestinationView/vobs/siren
ct findmerge activityname@/vob/**  -fcsets -nc -merge
```

Comment: I am getting this error now on doing what you said `cleartool: Error: Unable to access "/view/siren_sdhx/vob/siren/oam/sdh/pkg/definition.pkg": not a ClearCase object`

Comment: @yanivx do a `cd /view/siren_sdhx/vob/siren/oam/sdh/pkg/` and `cleartool ls`, to see the status associated to `definition.pkg`

Comment: Build.mk@@/main/siren_sdhx/CHECKEDOUT from /main/siren_sdhx/0 [checkedout but removed]
definition.pkg@@/main/siren_sdhx/CHECKEDOUT from /main/siren_sdhx/0 [checkedout but removed]
filelist.pkg@@/main/siren_sdhx/CHECKEDOUT from /main/siren_sdhx/0 [checkedout but removed]

Comment: Can you try a `touch definition.pk` followed by a `cleartool unco definition.pk`, before trying the findmerge again? Maybe that file was checked out before.

Comment: Just to add I created a fresh stream and a fresh view followed with a merge no checkouts done before hand. BTW where can i find this definition.pk file

Comment: @yanivx do you have the same error in the new view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57554/discussion-between-yanivx-and-vonc).