# Findmerge graphical using paramiko

Tags: clearcase, paramiko

I have a script on a remote clearcase server which I execute using paramiko invoke_shell.The script contains a cleartool findmerge command graphical but the graphical window never opens though I used x11 forwarding. It waits forever.I even added the checkout comments for the merge. I want the graphical window to be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you did setup your X-forwarding: see [this thread for example](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014125122):

1. Launch Exceed
2. Launch Putty

   - In the putty configuration window, select Connection, then SSH, and then X11 from the left side menus.
   - On the right side, select the checkbox for `Enable X11 forwarding` and set the X display location to "`localhost:0`" .
   - In the putty configuration window, select `Session` from the left side.
     Enter the `hostname` of a system to connect to Select the SSH protocol
     Save settings by selecting the `Save` button on the right.
   - Invoke session by double-clicking on hostname
3. from the server, run "`export DISPLAY=windows ip:0`"
4. You should be able to run any X-based tool or application
   e.g. `clearprojexp &`

---

The [OP Srikar Veeramallu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4587259/srikar-veeramallu)  mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668045/findmerge-graphical-using-paramiko/28668253#comment45634214_28668253):

> I am in a dynamic view set using `cleartool setview`

That explains why it "waits forever". A `setview` will create a sub-shell, which might not benefit from the same X11 forwarding as the main shell.
See "[Python and ClearCase `setview`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309)" for more details.

The workaround is to [use the full path of the view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27826673/6309).

Comment: With putty this works fine. But when I run it with python using paramiko module to connect and execute commands. The issue I mentioned above is encountered

Comment: @SrikarVeeramallu are you in a dynamic view set with `cleartool setview` in your python session?

Comment: yes I am in a dynamic view set using cleartool setview

Comment: @SrikarVeeramallu I knew it! Simply put: never use `cleartool setview`. Ever. It only brings trouble. Always use the full path of the dynamic view. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/27826673/6309, and, for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309.

Comment: @SrikarVeeramallu I have edited the answer and added the workaround.