# Unable to connect to VOB,getting i/o eror

Tags: clearcase

How to avoid the following error message:

```
ldndss02432$ cleartool setview dheeraj_unix_view2 
ldndss02432$ bash 
ldndss02432$ cleartool catcs 
element * CHECKEDOUT 
element * /main/LATEST 

ldndss02432$ cd /vobs/fo_ird_steed 
bash: cd: /vobs/fo_ird_steed: I/O error 
ldndss02432$
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do not use `cleartool setview` (it [brings only troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309))

Use the [full path of the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27825446/python-clearcase-download-vobs-popen-password-bash-program-sketchy/27826673#27826673):

```
cleartool dheeraj_unix_view2
cd /view/dheeraj_unix_view2/vobs/yourVob
```

Answer (score 1):

The vob was untagged. Tagging it resolved the issue.