# How to run multiple Unix commands in one shot

Tags: unix, ssh, clearcase, jsch, cleartool

I am trying to execute multiple commands in one shot but to my surprise only the first command is getting executed and the rest are skipped. And the command is

```
cleartool setview view1234 ; cleartool setactivity activity456 ; cd /vobs/app/src/epw/WEB-INF/scripts ; pwd
```

And the output of the above command is

```
You can now run 'clearquest' to start Rational ClearQuest.
```

But instead I'm expecting to see the following 3 lines of output:

```
You can now run 'clearquest' to start Rational ClearQuest.
Set activity "activity456" in view "view1234".
/vobs/app/src/epw/WEB-INF/scripts
```

My search efforts yielded few more variations for the same command by replacing semicolon(;) with ampersand (&) or pipe (|) but nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions/ideas on how to run multiple commands like above?

Comment: Try using `&&` instead of a single.

Comment: Matt-  The same result for &&. I mean only the first command gets executed and nothing after that. Even commands like pwd or ls doesn't work after view creation.

Comment: You're running that command from a shell prompt, right? If so, that should execute all three commands in sequence, assuming you have commands named `Cleartool` and `run`. How do you know the second and third commands aren't being executed? Try a simple example: `echo one ; echo two ; echo three'

Comment: @MattClark: That's not likely to help. The only difference `&&` would make is that the second and third commands *won't* run if a previous command fails.

Comment: Are any of those aliases to something else? `&&` works just fine for me to run multiple commands.

Comment: @KeithThompson it may make a difference in this context. A single `&` will spawn the process in a background thread and move right into the next, where as the `&&` will wait for the prior to finish before beginning the next.

Comment: @KeithThompson Your example will work. Because I tried running multiple commands like cd tesfolder && pwd && ls..
I see problm only when I run commands after set view command.
Is there any time delay command available n unix so I can try running that time delay after view creation and try other commands a little later like 2000 ms.

Comment: @MattClark Thanks for the sleep command but it doesn't help me get out of this.

Just adding one more interesting thing that I noticed.

cmd2 && cmd3 && cmd4 is executing each command in order. 
where as cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && cmd4 is just executing the first command.

where cmd1 = Cleartool setview viewname
cmd2 = cleartool setactivity activityName

Comment: As I already tried asking, is `Cleartool` an alias or sh function? Or a binary? Can you try running `echo $?` directly after cmd1? The output of this will be the return status code of the execution. A `0` will mean that everything preformed as expected, any other number will indicate an error, and `&&` will not continue.

Comment: @MattClark: The OP said the second and third commands were *skipped*. Though I suspect that's not what's really happening.

Comment: @MattClark Cleartool is a command line interface for IBM's clearcase tool. It helps to get things like checkout, check in, etc

I have tried to use your tip echo $? after my command but that doesn't print anything. It just prints the expected output after my command.

Servername: cleartool setview user_app_web_05.50_int_unix && echo $?
You can now run 'clearquest' to start Rational ClearQuest.

Comment: @user1423854: What happens if you run the commands one at a time: Run `Cleartool Setview viewname`, then run `Cleartool SetActivity activityname`, then run `run buildFile`. And again, do you really have a command called `run`?

Comment: `Cleartool setview user_app_web_05.50_int_unix && echo $?` -- That will do the `echo $?` only if the `cleartool` command succeeds. Change the `&&` to `;`, and it will show you the error status from the `Cleartool` command. (It's `Cleartool`, not `cleartool`, right?)

Comment: @KeithThompson 
1) if I run all those commands one by one it works.

2) there is no such command but i typed in normal English. Instead if the command is even Cleartool Setview viewname && echo 1 && echo 2
The output is just "You can now run 'clearquest' to start Rational ClearQuest" and it is not printing 1 and 2.

3) It is cleartool and not Cleartool.

Comment: This is why copy-and-paste is *very* important. You're showing us a command that's superficially similar to the one that's actually failing. It's very likely that your summary has omitted whatever is causing the problem. Please update your question to show the **exact** copy-and-pasted command that's failing. If you're getting an error message, include that as well.

Comment: @KeithThompson I have modified my question and there is no error that I am seeing only the response to the first command is printed as a result of running multiple commands.

Comment: Do you get a shell prompt after running that command, or does the first sub-command hang?

Comment: yes I do get the shell prompt and I am once again typing in the second command manually to get it executed.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use [`cleartool setview`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-66): [it forks the current shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309) in a subshell, which is why the rest is skipped when executed in a single line.
And which is why it works when executed one by one (the last two are executed in the subshell)

Always work with the [full path of the dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27826673/6309): `/view/aview/vobs/avob/...`, instead of `setview` (which you don't need).

If you must use [`cleartool setview`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-66), then use it with the `-exec` option ([as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32021329/6309)):

```
cleartool setview -login -exec "command 1; command 2; command 3" view_tag
```

In your case:

```
cleartool setview -exec 'cleartool setactivity activity456 ; cd /vobs/app/src/epw/WEB-INF/scripts ; pwd' view1234
```

---

Without setview:

The OP asks:

> Say my view named `humanbeing` is in `universe/planet/earth/humanbeing.vws`
>
> How do I use the **[`startview` command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-68)**?
> Is it something like

```
cleartool startview universe/planet/earth/humanbeing
```

> or

```
cleartool startview cd universe/planet/earth/humanbeing
```

> In both the cases it says the Error: Couldn't set view tag `universe/planet/earth/humanbeing`

To be sure, do a `cleartool lsview -s | grep humanbeing`: that will give you the view tag.

That should be:

```
cleartool startview humanbeing
cd /view/humanbeing/vobs/<avob>
```

`universe/planet/earth/humanbeing.vws` is the view *storage*, not a view tag.

Make sure that

- is mounted (`cleartool mount /vobs/avob`)
- `myapp/WEB-INF/scripts` is present in `/view/humanbeing/vobs/<avob>`

Don't try to do any symlink in `/vobs`: `/vobs` is a special MVFS (Multi-Version FileSystem) mounting point, not a regular folder.
Make sure your webapp search for apps in another path than `/vobs`.

Comment: Could you tell me how to get the full path of the dynamic view? 
I have an alias created for the dynamic (Integration) view and I am trying to set the view.

Comment: @user1423854 do not set the view. It only brings issue (read http://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309). For an example of the full path, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27826673/6309. Both links are in my answer.

Comment: I was able to find the myapp/WEB-INF/scripts folder under view/myview/myVOBS so now my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do as it seems to be part of a larger problem space, but ...

```
cleartool setact -view view1234 activity456
```

works to set an activity in the view, then

```
cd /view/view1234/vobs/app/src/epw/WEB-INF/scripts
```

will get you there. Or slap them together to get your result:

```
cleartool setact -view view1234 activity456 && cd /view/view1234/vobs/app/src/epw/WEB-INF/scripts && pwd
```

The statement `<stmt1> && <stmt2>` is shorthand for `if [[ <stmt1> ]]; then <stmt2>`

See [KSH man page](http://www2.research.att.com/sw/download/man/man1/ksh.html) for more information on executing unix commands "in one shot".

A semicolon (;) causes sequential execution of the preceding pipeline; an ampersand (&) causes asynchronous execution of the preceding pipeline (i.e., the shell does not  wait for that pipeline to finish). The symbol |& causes asynchronous execution of the preceding pipeline with a two-way pipe established to the parent shell; ... The symbol && ( | | ) causes the list  following it to be executed only if the preceding pipeline returns a zero (non-zero) value.

Comment: The `[[` in your pseudo-code is wrong, kind of.  The `sh` (and thus also `ksh` and Bash) syntax is simply `if stmt1; then stmt2; fi`

Comment: The pseudo code was not meant to be taken literally. Clarified. Nevertheless, it is preferred to place tests within [[ to avoid ambiguous results. Search SO for [[ vs [ for explanations

Comment: Many beginners misunderstand the syntax of `if` and try exactly this on the false assumption that `[[` (or `[`) is part of the syntax; implying that this is correct is misleading them IMHO. See e.g.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36371221/bash-if-statement-too-many-arguments for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to Clearcase to try things out but sometimes from past experience, you will need to RTFM, such tools with either accept a reverse pipe or an input script file, look in the documentation for syntax such as:

`Cleartool < echo` *command_sequence*

`echo` *command_sequence* `| Cleartool -` **or**

`Cleartool -f` *inputfile* or *command sequence* **or**

`Cleartool -c` *inputfile* or *command sequence* **or**

`Cleartool run` *inputfile* or *command sequence* **or**

*If you do find some variant of the above does the trick please let us know by posting your own answer so that the next person with the problem can benefit.*

Comment: None of those wouldn't work if the first cleartool command is 'setview': it forks the shell.

Comment: If you [RTFM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/cleartool.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-0&lang=en), you'll see such options are not supported.