# Running a Git build inside a ClearCase View in tcsh

Tags: git, jenkins, clearcase, tcsh

I have a project stored in git that must be built outside of clearcase and then executed inside of a Clearcase view. All of the builds and execution must be done inside of `tcsh` due to restrictions on external scripts.

The Clearcase view requires `tcsh` to successfully execute the commands.

To automate this process, I would like to use jenkins.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out and wanted to record it somewhere.

To execute a different shell inside of the `Execute shell` build step in jenkins, I use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -xF
source env.csh
make
echo DONE
```

**NOTE:** a newline is required at the end of each script to make sure that the last command is executed. I usually just `echo DONE` to make sure that every step is executed.

To run commands inside of the Clearcase view in `tcsh``, I use the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh -xF
setenv SHELL /bin/tcsh
cleartool setview -login -exec "command 1; command 2; command 3" view_tag
echo DONE
```

Hope this helps!