# How do you change a user's primary unix group in a ColdFusion rsh command?

Tags: unix, coldfusion, clearcase, rsh

We use an rsh command to check files into ClearCase:

```
<cfexecute name="C:\cygwin64\bin\rsh.exe"
    arguments="-n -l #USERNAME# #SERVER# ""cleartool setview -exec '#KSH_FILE# -user #USERNAME# -dir #VOB_DIRECTORY#' #CLEARCASE_VIEW#"" "
    timeout="180"
    variable="CHECKIN_FILE_CONTENT">
</cfexecute>
```

But are running into an issue where a user's primary unix group is set to a different group than the VOB the user is trying to check the file into.

I need to run a `newgrp` command right before executing the `#KSH_FILE#`

I was sure this would work:

```
<cfexecute name="C:\cygwin64\bin\rsh.exe"
    arguments="-n -l #USERNAME# #SERVER# ""newgrp #GROUP#; cleartool setview -exec '#KSH_FILE# -user #USERNAME# -dir #VOB_DIRECTORY#' #CLEARCASE_VIEW#"" "
    timeout="180"
    variable="CHECKIN_FILE_CONTENT">
</cfexecute>
```

But it keeps timing out.. no errors, just spins and stops.

---UPDATE---
Upon further testing, cfexcute and rsh don't seem to allow multiple commands. Here is a sample test I tried that yielded the same problems:

```
<cfexecute name="C:\cygwin64\bin\rsh.exe"
    arguments="-n -l #USERNAME# #SERVER# ""newgrp #GROUP#; id -a > results.txt"" "
    timeout="180">
</cfexecute>
```

Comment: The solution I am currently working adds the newgrp command to the '#KSH_FILE#'. If anyone has any more advice on why multiple commands are not executable in a cfexecute command I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a `launchcheckin.ksh` script to change the user's group within the shell. I just pass the commands that I wanted to execute as arguments to the script, change the group in the script and execute the commands in the newgrp stream! We've had this out in production for 6 months without a hitch.

**launchcheckin.ksh**

```
FILE="$1"
GROUP="$2"
COUNT=1
for argument in $*
  do
    if [ ${COUNT} -gt 2 ]
      then
        ARGUMENTS="${ARGUMENTS} ${argument}"
      fi
    ((COUNT+=1))
done

newgrp ${GROUP} << EOF
${FILE} ${ARGUMENTS}
EOF
```

**Updated command**

```
<cfexecute name="C:\cygwin64\bin\rsh.exe"
    arguments="-n -l #USERNAME# #SERVER# ""cleartool setview -exec '/launchcheckin.ksh #KSH_FILE# #GROUP# #ARGUMENTS#' #CLEARCASE_VIEW#"" "
    timeout="180"
    variable="CHECKIN_FILE_CONTENT">
</cfexecute>
```

Comment: Nice feedback, more precise than my answer. +1

Comment: Thanks for coming back and updating. +1

Answer (score 1):

Don't use (as [I explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31866188/6309)) [`cleartool setview`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-66): it [forks the current shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309) which is why the the newgrp and setview don't  communicate well: they trigger their own shells.

If you need to do anything with a dynamic view, use its full path (`/view/<aview>/vobs/<avob>`), don't use `setview`. That way, you can use `newgrp` if you need to.

Comment: VonC, thank you I didn't consider that the commands would be executed in different shells. Do you have an example command I could use instead of setview?

Comment: @Klog simply use the command you want, but in the full path of the dynamic view: `/view/myView/vobs/myvob/...` (instead of `/vobs/myvob`, as set by the `setview` command)

Comment: After talking with our ClearCase guru, this solution will not work for us.

Comment: @Klog OK. Is there any reason which was mentioned?

Comment: Sorry, they didn't give me any details :/