# Passing a Variable to a script calling itself

Tags: perl, view, clearcase

My Script is storing a ClearCase View in a Variable. To operate in this View, the Script needs to call itself inside the View again, after it started the View.
The Code looks like this

```
 if($params{ViewSet} eq 'no')
    {
       # Start the View
       # Store the View in $View
       # Call the Script in the new-set View with parameter -ViewSet yes
    }
if($params{ViewSet} eq 'yes')
    {
      # Do Work inside the View
    }
```

The problem is, obviously the Variable `$View` is not defined when I call my script the second time, since it is defined in the first if loop.

Can I pass the View I stored in `$View` when I call the Script the second time?
Setting the View before entering the if-Statements would not word, I would start the View two times then.

Comment: Why are you doing this?  Stating the actual problem you are trying to solve would help here.

Comment: @dan1111 This is a ClearCase specific problem that I know well. I have answered it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Call the Script in the new-set View with parameter -ViewSet

If that involve calling [`cleartool setview`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-66), **don't**: [`setview` spawns a subshell i](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309)n which what you have defined in your script won't be visible.

When your script needs to access the [dynamic view started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31866188/6309), do use the *full* dynamic view path:

```
/view/myDynView
# under which you would see:
/view/myDynView/vobs/MyVob
```

Comment: I know about the subshell problem, I wanted to know it there would be any Option for a workaround. I have found a working solution for myself, but thanks for your hint ;) The Solution was first to get the Viewname from the View I am using, and store all information about the new view in a new variable. That way, I didn't actually pass the Variable from one view(shell) into another, but created the exact same one in the new View. Worked for my problem.