# ClearCase.ClearTool returns No view context available error

Tags: hook, clearcase, clearquest, cal

I am trying to run the following code, but the got `#error 1` at `startview` command, and `#error 2` in `desc` command.

```
    use Win32::OLE; 
    $ct = Win32::OLE->new('ClearCase.ClearTool') or die "Could not create ClearTool object\n";  
    $view = "ccadm01_UARK_DEV";
    $output = $ct->CmdExec("pwv") or die("Cleartool returned error: ", Win32::OLE->LastError(), "\n"); 
    print ("pwv \$output = $output\n");

# error 1 : cleartool return error 0   
    $output = $ct->CmdExec("startview ccadm01_UARK_DEV") or die("Cleartool returned error: ", Win32::OLE->LastError(), "\n"); 

    $CWD = $view_dir;  
    print( "Current directory: $CWD\n");

# error 2: No view context available
    $output = $ct->CmdExec("describe -fmt \"%[versions]Cp\" activity:USR0200004985\@\\Unix_PVOB") or die("Cleartool returned error: ", Win32::OLE->LastError(), "\n"); 
    print ("desc \$output = $output\n");
```

For #error 1, I tried the same command from DOS, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your `$view` is a valid dynamic view tag for [`cleartool startview`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm) to work.
(make sure to [*not* use `cleartool setview`, as it spawns a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33932379/6309))

Also if it returns error 0, you can assume it has worked: CAL might return an "error", but status 0 should mean the command has been executed.

An error different from 0, though, means something went wrong.

And you need to `cd` into that view (`/view/<viewTag>` or `m:\<viewTag>`) for a [`cleartool descr`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-9&lang=en) to work.
That one, executed in the wrong folder, is supposed to fail, hence "error 2".

---

The [OP Jirong Hu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2501936/jirong-hu) points [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35236379/clearcase-cleartool-returns-no-view-context-available-error/35237837?noredirect=1#comment58202269_35237837) to [Using Perl with Rational ClearCase Automation Library (CAL)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4711.html) and [this script as an example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/nov01/changeset_report.txt).

Comment: I even changed to $ct->CmdExec("startview ccadm01_UARK_DEV") , still the same error, the view tag is right and same command can be run from command line cleartool. the 2nd command I use $CWD = $view_dir; to cd into the view, because the backticks doesn't work too. Is this CAL still supported in CCCQ v8?

Comment: @Jir try also a pwv, to check where you are. Also, before your startview, make sure the view is stopped, just to check if the CAL startview is working.

Comment: pwc output in None. cleartool startview can run multiple time even it's started. I always run this just to make sure. Oh, I was wrong about command line, it fails from DOC command line too, code and output shown as below: I put it into answer.

Comment: @JirongHu do not put it as an answer. Answers are for answers only. Edit your question ;)

Comment: @JirongHu in your second `CAL` command (the '`describe` call one), could you try `cd m:\ccadm01_UARK_DEV && describe -fmt ...`

Comment: thanks for telling me I shall edit the original question. Anyway, it didn't work so I changed to using this way, problem resolved. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/4711.html. Thanks a lot for your time, during the weekend!

Comment: @JirongHu Great. I have included a link to that article in the answer for more visibility.