# can i use jdeveloper with clearcase dynamic views?

Tags: ide, clearcase, jdeveloper, dynamic-view

Jdeveloper (Oracle's Java IDE) has a clearcase plugin built by oracle too.
I have worked with it with clearcase snapshots everything works find.

My question is, how to use it with a dynamic view (I am on linux) ?
How do i "set view" with dynamic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check your ClearCase version: the [Oracle jdeveloper ClearCase plugin](http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/131167.xml#oracle.jdeveloper.clearcase) are quite old.

[This thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014805633) mentions that JDeveloper 11.1.2 would only support ClearCase 7.0.x, not 7.1.x or later.

But anyway, you can try and see if jdeveloper recognizes a view when using the full path of a dynamic view:

```
/view/view-tag/full-pathname
/view/myDynamicView/vobs/avob/...
```

In other words, you do not have to use `cleartool setview` (which [I have always disliked anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33932379/6309)): you can point jdeveloper to the path of the dynamic view (provided the [vob used by the config spec is mounted](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.dev.doc/topics/cc_dev/to_activate_vob.htm))

Comment: i am using jdeveloper 11.1.1.9.0. and 
clearcase:
 ClearCase version 8.0.1.3-iFix01 (Tue Apr 22 18:14:02 EDT 2014) (8.0.1.03.01_2014A.1.FCS)
cleartool                         8.0.1.5 (Mon Aug 18 23:14:21 2014)

Comment: @thedrs Then I do not know if that more recent version of ClearCase is supported. But as long as you stay away of "`cleartool setview`", you still can try and see of jdeveloper can work with a dynamic view through it full and complete absolute path.