# daemon process mount failed

Tags: linux, process, clearcase, daemon

I am programming a Linux distribution C program. When daemon process read a MSG from the client, it will fork a child process, then mount a "NFS" dir to local host and do the compute task on this NFS dir.
However this is NFS is IBM ClearCase dynamic view which is called "MVFS" rather than "NFS".
So I have to exec "`cleartool setview xxyyzz`" to mount this view.
But I tried several methods such as `fork() + execvp`, `system(shell)`, but never succeed.
Below is the code and shell:

```
void my_system();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  pid_t pid=fork();
  if(pid!=0) exit(0);
  if(setsid()==-1)
  {
    printf("setsid failed.");
    exit(-1);
  }
  umask(0);
  chdir("/tmp");
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    close(i);
  FILE* logfd=fopen("/tmp/ccdcc.log","a+");
  dup2(fileno(logfd),STDOUT_FILENO);
  dup2(fileno(logfd),STDERR_FILENO);
  fclose(logfd);
  my_system();  //method1
  system("/tmp/ccdccshell");  //method2
  sleep(SEVERALTIME);
}

void my_system()
{
  pid_t pid=fork();
  if(pid!=0) return;
  char *arg1[]={"cleartool","setview","zzzzzz"};
  char *arg2[]={"cd","/proj/layer/mak"};
  char *arg3[]={"mycmd"};
  execvp("cleartool",arg1);
  execvp("cd",arg2);
  execvp("mycmd",NULL);
}

xxx@yyy> cat /tmp/ccdccshell
#!/bin/sh
#this command will mount a dynamic view and source some profile.
cleartool setview zzzzzz
#this path is under the mounted path
cd /proj/layer/mak
#to test where we are
pwd
#call my prog.
mycmd
```

I failed "`cleartool....`" everytime. There's no view been mounted.
"`pwd`" always return the path "`/`".

Could you tell me how to finish my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use [`cleartool setview`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-66): it [spawns a subshell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309) which would not be visible from your sameon.

Simply use the [full dynamic view path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27826673/6309):

```
/view/myDynView
# under which you would see:
/view/myDynView/vobs/MyVob
```

All you need is for the [view to be started](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31866188/6309).

Comment: Could you please more particular, how to make the view to be started and what could be done after get the full dynamic view path? thank you!

Comment: @jianhui for the starting part: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31866188/6309 (as mentioned in my answer)

Comment: @jianhui "what could be done after get the full dynamic view path": nothing, you just make sure to use that path in your daemon process.