# unix script for initial setup using ssh, newgrp, cleartool setview: how to avoid subshell?

Tags: unix, ssh, cleartool

I have following requirements for a project initial setup

1. need to login to remote server using `ssh <servername>`
2. need to change default group using `newgrp <grpname>`
3. need to set the clearcase view using `cleartool setview <viewname>`
4. change dir to clearcase vobs using `cd /vobs/proj/dita`

I am trying to write a script which I source when I open a new terminal which does all the above and give me the terminal with required setup.

Now the problem is, 3 out of 4 above commands create a new shell.

Can you help me to achieve this?

Comment: Note to moderators: this is *not* "too broad", this is the kind of question I have been answering for the past 10 years. If you know anything about ClearCase, this is a very specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Do no use [`cleartool setview`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm) (which does spawn a subshell, [as I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252436/python-and-clearcase-setview), and as you found out)

Use, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40347698/6309), the full path of the view you want to access in your ssh session:

```
/view/view-tag-name/vobs/some/path
```

That way, you are sure to remain in the same shell.