# How can I add commands to be executed when setting a view?

Tags: shell, hook, clearcase, cleartool, subshell

Using cleartool, when you `cleartool setview`, a subshell is opened apparently (you can `exit` it and leave the view). I was wondering - how can I get more commands to be executed, or settings made, when this subshell starts? Of course, I don't mean code which executes when *any* shell starts, just when cleartool starts one.

Answer (score 0):

A [`cleartool setview`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm) does not source anything (any shrc/bashrc) when spawning its subshell.

I have always advised [against setview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309), precisely to avoid the subshell issue.

It would be easier to get a script which would:

- execute/source additional commands
- switch the full view path `/view/AViewName/vobs/aVob/...` instead of relying on the `/vobs` setview chroot trick.

Or, use the `-exec` option of `setview` to source settings *and* execute a script.

Comment: By "chroot trick" you mean the fact that there's chrooting to `/view/AViewName`? Also, my shell could theoretically detect what the parent process was, and act accordingly if it ClearCase/Cleartool - couldn't it?

Comment: @einpoklum yes for chroot. And the subshell (https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) would not invoke anything. The script executed within that subshell might detect its parent shell indeed. That seems complex compared using the full view path directly within the *current* shell.

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page for setview, it takes an -exec parameter.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm

That can be used to run a script if you wish. As @Vonc mentioned, setview is a chroot environment, and the root of a view (/view/myview) will show the / filesystem to transparently support the chroot.

If you're scripting things on Unix, and want to follow VonC's advice about not using setview, you would need to set/detect a view in the script. "cleartool pwv -wdview" will tell you the view context of the current working directory. (See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_pwv.htm)

From personal experience, it's usually not a good idea to reach between views during audited builds, if that is what your script does. But some people use a common view for trigger scripts under source control...