# VS Code:Remote SSH - How to open files from a clearcase dynamic view

Tags: clearcase, vscode-remote-ssh

I connect to my Oracle Linux build server using SSH from Windows Terminal, set the Clearcase view and then view/edit code using Vi.

Now, I am trying to use Visual Studio Code - Remote SSH to connect to the server and edit code directly from Windows PC.

I am able to connect to the server from VS Code and able to set clearcase view from VS Code Terminal. But if I try to open the folder in VS File Explorer attached to my view I am not seeing any files. I can see the files from VS Code Terminal though.

Kindly provide suggestions to see the files in VS Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`cleartool setview`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/rational-clearcase/9.0.0?topic=ucm-setview) (to mount a dynamic view onto `/vobs`) is not the recommended best practice, as it [spawns a new process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252612/6309) which might not be correctly interpreted within the VSCode Remote SSH session.

To validate that, try and access the same folder using the full view path `/view/AViewName/vobs/aVob/.../yourFolder`, without setting any view (and assuming the Vob is already mounted).
See if your files are visible then.

Comment: Thanks a lot @VonC. I can see the file using the full view path.

Comment: @neoraghav Then that would be your workaround. Not as straightforward as using a set view but it will work with an SSH session.

Comment: Sure. We will be shifting to git sooner. Till then Ill stick with this approach. Thanks again.

Comment: There is an upcoming vs code integration that should help with this.

Comment: @BrianCowan Great! Is there any link/documentation reference, or is it still an internal development in progress?

Comment: Internal development. It's still on the roadmap, which any CC customer can ask for a briefing from the product manager.